# Unity Button doesn’t accept function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this problem. I wrote a script with a method when interacting with which the player exits the game, but when I wanted to bind it to the button, and I realised that it didn’t work . In the **OnClick()** component, I attached my script, but for some reason the method is not attached.How can I attach my method?

[image]

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Also [`[unity-container]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity-container/info) is completely unrelated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty `GameObject`, attach your `credits.cs` to it then assign this gameobject to the `OnClick()`, then Credits > (Your method).

Make sure your method is `public`.